# Souma now a Elite 10 after beating Eizan?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

In the latest chapter of the Manga, Chapter 147, Souma beats Eizan in a shokugeki. The terms were for Eizan to stop destroying the Polar Star Dorm, but does Souma get to also usurp Eizan's position in the Elite 10 as the no. 9 spot (I believe Eizan is number 9 but not sure) because he beat him in a shokugeki? Or is there not enough information to answer?

Comment: The rules of Shokugeki are set beforehand. It was cleared quite clearly by Isshiki, saying he won't bet his seat in the Elite 10 even if Souma bets his life or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

> Each side must lay out their "compensation", or something they must give up if they were to lose the challenge. Both sides must agree that the compensation of the duel equate with each other.

http://shokugekinosoma.wikia.com/wiki/Shokugeki

I guess the battle will only save the polar star dorm. Originally, whatever they bet before the Shokugeki is what they'll get when they win. This means if Souma wants to dethrone him, he'll need to propose another battle asking for the position if he wins.

But we'll see on the next chapter what would be the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, Eizan Etsuya is still in Elite Ten, in chapter 153 The Venue of Death, Eizan actually said that he doesn't care if he was released or even exiled from the school, however, Azami Nakiri still keep him for now.

[image: chapter 153]